# How can I access a JS object property whose value is an unknown integer?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, mediawiki-api

The JSON response returned from this wikipedia API call is a series of nested objects. To travel down the object property chain and access the text of interest, I have to first access a property whose value is a random number, dependent upon the wikipedia page I query by title.

An example for the page titled `"San%20Francisco"` (page id = 49728):

**Object Property Chain**:

```
responseJSON.wiki[0].query.pages[<<page id>>].extract
```

Example API Call: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/?origin=*&format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=San%20Francisco

Is there some way that I can identify the property whose value is a random integer? There is only one child of pages in the chain whose value is an integer. I cannot think of another solution and do not know of any JSON parsing method that would be effective.

I am inexperienced with AJAX requests and am making my ajax call in this way using jQuery. I would like to mention this in case I am doing something naive:

```
var getWiki = function (obj) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" +
            "?origin=*" + "&format=json" +
            "&action=query" + "&prop=extracts" +
            "&exintro=" + "&explaintext=" + "&titles=" +
            obj.position,
        method: 'GET'
    });
};
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

If your `object` has only a single key, you can get it using `Object.keys(object)[0]` and then perform a dynamic bracket-notation property access on the original `object`. (This is what the `dig` utility does in the example below.)

Also note that you can use `.promise()` to make handling your JSON response a bit tidier. I would suggest you add `type: 'json'` to your AJAX request, too, so that you don't have to parse the string data yourself.

```js
function getWiki(obj) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" +
      "?origin=*" + "&format=json" +
      "&action=query" + "&prop=extracts" +
      "&exintro=" + "&explaintext=" + "&titles=" +
      obj.position,
    method: 'GET',
    type: 'json'
  }).promise()
}


function dig(object) {
  return object[Object.keys(object)[0]]
}


getWiki({
    position: 'San Francisco'
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    console.log(
      dig(json.query.pages).extract //=> 'San Francisco (SF) ...'
    )
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there is always a single property on pages object then you can try either method:

```js
if (typeof Object.values !== 'function') {
  Object.values = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
}

const responseJSON = {
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "49728": {
        "pageid": 49728,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "San Francisco",
        "extract": "Some text"
      }
    }
  }
}

const pages = responseJSON.query.pages;

const extractedWithKeys = pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]];
const extractedObjValues = Object.values(pages)[0];

console.log(extractedWithKeys, extractedObjValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without `Object.keys` or other similar tricks if you add the `indexpageids` parameter to the query.

Example API call: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&indexpageids=1&titles=San+Francisco&exintro=1&explaintext=1

Example JSON output:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pageids": [
            "49728"
        ],
        "pages": {
            "49728": {
                "pageid": 49728,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "San Francisco",
                "extract": "San Francisco (initials SF) <snip>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use something like `data.query.pages[data.query.pageids[0]].extract` to get the extract (although bear in mind that sometimes no pages may be returned, depending on what query you use).

Wikipedia's [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) is useful for discovering parameters like `indexpageids` - experimenting there is usually quicker than reading the docs.